# Finding an object with the biggest (global) value in an array with repeating entries

Tags: java

I have an array of Objects which includes products that has been sold and the amount of how many were sold in that one order. There may be one product appearing many times.  I am trying to create a code, which would return the most popular product.  e.g. Object1 10, Object 2 15, Object1 5, Object3 4 and it should return Object1 and the number 15 (10+5). Order has parameters product name and quantity, with getters and setters.

My idea was to use a set, which would get rid of all the duplicates (code example below), however it turned out to be a bust, since set would not work in this case and I wasn't able to even finish it with a set. I don't know what else to try. Thanks!

```
public class Orders {

    private Product[] orders;

    public Orders() {
        orders = new order[0];
    }


    public void add(Order order) {
        Order[] newOrder = Arrays.copyOf(orders,
        orders.length + 1);
        newOrder[newOrder.length - 1] = order;
        orders = newOrders;
    }
    // the method described starts here
    public Product findTopProduct() {
        int[] array;
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i=0; i<orders.length; i++) {
            set.add(orders[i].getProductName());
        }
        array = new int[set.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<orders.length; i++) {
            for (int i1=0; i1<set.size();i1++) {
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A `Set` deliberately *disregards* number.  Maybe you need something that … *maps* an object to a count.

Comment: It would help us if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: @DavisHerring I thought about using map, but I am quite inexperienced when it comes to the JCF tools like map, so it's outside my skillset. Would you be so kind to send me a code example / solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a little bit wider quest (find the max, min, average...). There is one powerful class called [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html)

You can try to understand it and "exstract" the desired data.

I'll give you an example how to use the `Map` collection and what would be the output for some sample data:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Answer {

    static class Product{
        private String name;
        private int noOfSales;

        public Product(String name, int noOfSales){
            this.name = name;
            this.noOfSales = noOfSales;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public int getNoOfSales(){
            return noOfSales;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Product[] products = {
                new Product("tea", 4),
                new Product("apple", 12),
                new Product("tea", 15)
        };

        Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> mapOfProducts =
        Arrays.stream(products)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Product::getName,
                        Collectors.summarizingInt(Product::getNoOfSales)));

        System.out.println(mapOfProducts);


    }
}
```

The output is:

> {apple=IntSummaryStatistics{count=1, sum=12, min=12, average=12.000000, max=12}, tea=IntSummaryStatistics{count=2, sum=19, min=4, average=9.500000, max=15}}

Please, notice that finding only maximum [reducing method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)). (This contains an example code)

Answer (score 0):

This is best addressed using [Map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-interface-java-examples/) data structure. You need to *map* each product name to its quantity across all orders you have. I'm using [HashMap](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap) in Java, but you also need to understand the `Map` data structure and how/when to use it, here's the way I would implement it (I'm assuming you `Product` class has another property called `quantity`):

```
public Product findTopProduct() {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); // this map should contain each product name pointing to its quantity across all orders (obj1 -> 10, obj2 -> 15, obj3 -> 4, ...)
    for (int i=0; i<orders.length; i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(orders[i].getProductName())) { // if it already exists in map, then you need to add the quantity only and not create a new entry
            map.put(orders[i].getProductName(), map.get(orders[i].getProductName() + orders[i].getQuantity()));
        } else { // add the productName maping to its quantity
            map.put(orders[i].getProductName(), order[i].getQuantity);
        }
    }
    String productName = null;
    Integer max = null;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) { // loop on map entries
        if(productName == null && max == null) { // the first iteration they are both null
            productName = entry.getKey();
            max = entry.getValue();
            continue;
        }
        if(entry.getValue() > max) { // maximize
            max = entry.getValue();
            productName = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    Product product = new Product(productName, max);
    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static Product findTopProduct(Product[] orders) {
        Map<String,List<Product>> var0 = Stream.of(orders)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName));
        int maxCount = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Product top = null;
        for(Map.Entry<String,List<Product>>entry : var0.entrySet()) {
            int size = entry.getValue().size();
            if (size > maxCount) {
                top = entry.getValue().get(0);
                maxCount = size;
            }
        }
        return top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This `getTopProduct` method returns a new `Product` with the product name and total quantity.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //sample list of objects containing productName and quantity fields
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        Product p1 = new Product("toy", 10);
        Product p2 = new Product("car", 14);
        Product p3 = new Product("food", 2);
        Product p4 = new Product("toy", 6);
        productList.add(p1);
        productList.add(p2);
        productList.add(p3);
        productList.add(p4);

        Product topProduct = getTopProduct(productList);
        System.out.println("Most sold product: " + topProduct.getProductName() + ", " + topProduct.getQuantity());
    }

    private static Product getTopProduct(List<Product> productList) {
        //map to hold products and total quantity
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        //populate the map
        for(Product product : productList) {            
            if(map.containsKey(product.getProductName())) {
                //if product already exists in map, add on the quantity
                map.put(product.getProductName(), map.get(product.getProductName()) + product.getQuantity());
            }else {
                //if product doesnt exist in map yet, add it
                map.put(product.getProductName(), product.getQuantity());
            }
        }

        //find the highest value in the map which is the product with highestQuantity
        int highestQuantity = Collections.max(map.values());

        String productWithHighestQuantity = "";
        //go through map to find which product had the highest quantity
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue()==highestQuantity) {
                productWithHighestQuantity = entry.getKey();
                break;
            }
        }

        return new Product(productWithHighestQuantity, highestQuantity);
    }
}
```